# Children's 80s TV show sci-fi with puppets

Tags: story-identification

There was a children's show in the 80s.  I remember some ugly scary looking puppets (aliens?) and tic-tac-toe i think played on large on cubes, rotating metal hoops.

It's not much to go on I know.  But it's bugging me...

Comment: When I hear "scifi" and "puppets", my mind immediately goes "[*Thunderbirds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_(TV_series))", but that's too early. Maybe [*Terrahawks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrahawks)? Some of those puppets are pretty freaky-looking, and the end-credits usually involved a game of tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Jason Baker suggests in the comments, this is Terrahawks.

This was a Gerry Anderson production from the 1980s, which explains why it's both SF and puppet based.

You can see the Tic Tac Toe game in the end credit [on youTube](https://youtu.be/6nJ2vyXKOOE), and is played out between the (heroic) Zeroids and the evil cube robots [image]

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrahawks) page is pretty compehensive; the main villain was Zelda [image]

Comment: And if someone can convert that YouTube link into an embedded video, I'd be grateful - I can't figure out how I'm supposed to do that.

Comment: Usually, you just paste it in. It won't show up on the preview, though. Oh, and for some reason, combining https and the "you.tube" bits makes it glitch.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Ah, thank you. I didn't see it on preview, and assumed I'd been doing it wrong!

Comment: Intitial reaction: Well that doesn't fit the "ugly scary looking puppets" criteria at all. Scrolls downs: AARGHHH!

Comment: @Ashandes - perhaps I should have wrapped it in a spoiler tag...

Comment: Yes, please wrap in spoiler tag.  I'm scared all over again... Hides in corner...